LangChain/Next.js chatbot displaying incorrect sources
I'm building a chatbot using LangChain, Next.js,and CosmosDB (vector store). My implementation is based on this template:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain-nextjs-template/blob/main/app/api/chat/retrieval/route.ts
I'm trying to display the source documents used by the LLM in my UI, but I'm facing two issues:

Source documents not displaying: Despite using a StreamingTextResponse to send the source information in the headers as JSON chunks (see code snippet below), they don't show up in my UI. There are no console errors.
Incorrect sources: When some source documents do appear, they are not the ones actually used by the LLM or contain unrelated information.

Here's the part supposed to return the sources:
return new StreamingTextResponse(stream, {
      headers: {
        "x-message-index": (previousMessages.length + 1).toString(),
        "x-sources": serializedSources,
      },
    });


So my questions:

Is my approach to streaming source documents via StreamingTextResponse wrong?
How can I ensure I'm associating the correct source documents with each LLM response?
What debugging techniques can I use to pinpoint where the source information is getting lost or mismatched?

